# Autowiring a Spring Bean from a JSF Controller

Tags: spring, jsf

I receive NullPoin Exception while calling any method of a Spring Bean, as it seems it is not injected in the container. And I can' t understand why.

Th particularity is that the Controller is using JSF and the Beans are Spring Bean: may be is this the problem? Or just configuration mistake?

The (simplified) code and config is:

Context.xml (called from root context)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:plugin="http://www.springframework.org/schema/plugin"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/plugin http://www.springframework.org/schema/plugin/spring-plugin.xsd">

<!--===========LANGUAGE_TO_LOCALE SERVICE CONFIG BEGIN===========-->

<bean
    id="languagesCountryLocaleHelper"
    class="com.i18n.MyControllerHelper"
    scope="request" />


</beans>
```

JSF COntroller:

```
@RequestScoped
@Named    
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyControllerHelper helper;

    public void doSomething() {
    helper.doSomething ();
    }
}
```

MyControllerHelper:

```
@Component
public class MyControllerHelper {

    public void doSomething() {
    // do something useful
    }
}
```

So, this is the simplified case.. do you have any idea on where my error can be?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try using `@Inject` instead of `@Autowired`.

Comment: Already tried. But with no different result, thank you in the while.

Comment: I don't think you can inject into a final field, ever.  You also shouldn't instantiate it that way.

Comment: You are right John Ament, the final was an orphan of the workarount I had to use (instantiate with no Dependency Injection but with new ControllerHelper() ). Eclipse added the final modifier.
I correct it for clarity and in the project to be sure it wasn'  t originally with it. 
Unfortunatly it didn' t help. :(

Comment: You've annotated `ControllerHelper` as a component and try to autowire `MyControllerHelper`, is the latter also properly annotated? Also, have you enabled component scanning or defined the bean manually on your configuration? What about defining annotation-config?

Comment: Only here in this semplification there is this error between MyControllerHelper and ControllerHelper as I have edited here for semplicity and it is quite hard to catch this kind of error in this editing GUI. :) Thank you, I correct here.
I didn' t enable component scanning, I just defined manually the beans.
I look after annotation-config.xml and I try also to make some tests here.. it sounds a good way.. I will let you know! 
Thx!

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, it's not an XML file itself, just a tag for your configuration. Like [described here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config).

Comment: I checked t0mmpa, <context:annotation-config/>  was already present in the original configuration of the root-context.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem injecting MyControllerHelper through:

```
helper = AppContext.getBean(MyControllerHelper.class);
```

After that, the bean is instantiated and injected and at cascade all the other beans after it.
I suppose it was due by the fact as JSF Controller the Controller instance Object was in a different container now automatically aware of Spring Beans.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
private MyControllerHelper helper = new MyControllerHelper();
```

change to this

```
@Autowired
private MyControllerHelper languagesCountryLocaleHelper;
```

Comment: the instantiation through new MyControllerHelper was the work around. removed from the example, thx.